# Liquid template to get XML node and child nodes xml as it is to json format

Tags: azure, xslt, maps, azure-logic-apps, liquid-template

I am trying Liquid template to convert XML to Json with some transformation. I have sample XML as shown below

**Sample XML:**

```
<Employees>
 <Employee>
  <name>abc</name>
  <summary>
   <Age>15</Age>
   <tag1>dd</tag1>
   <tag2>dd</tag2>
   <tag2>dd</tag2>
  </summary>
 </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**My Liquid template**

```
{
"Root": 
    [
     {% for employees in content.Employees %}
    {
        "Name": "{{employees.name}}",
        "Summary": "summary is {{employees.summary}}",
  "Age": "{{employees.summary.Age}}"
    },
    {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

I got the **Output** as below

```
{
"Root": [
 {
  "Name": "abc",
  "Summary": "summary is ",
  "Age": "15"
 }
 ]
}
```

For Summary json node I want to display complete summary xml node and child nodes as it is(xml format), but now I am receiving empty. I tried searching to achieve this in liquid template and didn't get any option to achieve this. If not possible then what alternatives can be used in Azure logic apps.

**Expected output:**

```
 {
"Root": [
 {
  "Name": "abc",
  "Summary": "summary is <summary><Age>15</Age><tag1>dd</tag1><tag2>dd</tag2><tag2>dd</tag2></summary>",
  "Age": "15"
 }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 3 can transform your XML to JSON with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Employees">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="map { 'Root' : 
                  array { 
                      Employee ! map { 'Name' : data(name), 'Summary' : 'Summary is ' || serialize(summary), 'Age' : number(summary/Age) }
                  }
              }"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
 {
  "Root": [
     {
      "Summary":"Summary is <summary><Age>15<\/Age><tag1>dd<\/tag1><tag2>dd<\/tag2><tag2>dd<\/tag2><\/summary>",
      "Name":"abc",
      "Age":15
     }
   ]
 }
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkM/1

I think you can use XSLT 3 by now, based on Saxon 9 .NET, in Azure apps.

Comment: This works as expected. But when i run in logic app the namespace gets added to the summary like <summary xmlns:xsi=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\">.  One more thing i wanted is check a condition like Employee.tag2=somevalue then only do the logic of map

Comment: @techresearch, I can't tell why you get those namespaces, unless they are declared somewhere up the tree e.g. on the `Employees` element. As for the second issue about checking a condition, inside of XSLT you can obviously easily use `Employee[tag2 = 'somevalue'] ! map  { .. }` instead of the `Employee ! map { .. }` shown above, to populate the JSON array only from `Employee` elements meeting that condition.

Comment: Nice!! This xml conditioning working as expected.  As you mentioned In my original XML i do have namespace up in the tree so it comes up.If i remove that namespace it wont come up in summary. So is there anyway i can handle this removal of namespace from output summary in XSLT itself.

Comment: @techresearch, you can push the summary element through a mode that uses `copy-namespaces="no"`. If you need help on that better raise it as a separate question.

Comment: I have created new question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098112/remove-namespace-from-serialized-xml-in-xslt