# Remove namespace from serialized XML in XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt, azure-logic-apps, xslt-3.0

I am trying convert XML to Json with some transformation in XSLT 3. I have sample XML as shown below

**Sample XML:**

```
<Root>
 <Employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <Employee>
      <name>abc</name>
     </Employee>
      <Employee>
      <name>def</name>
     </Employee>
  <summary>
   <Age>15</Age>
   <tag1>dd</tag1>
   <tag2>dd</tag2>
   <tag2>dd</tag2>
  </summary>
 </Employees>
</Root>
```

**My XSLT template**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
version="3.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/Root">
<xsl:for-each select="Employees">
    <xsl:sequence select="map { 'Root' : 
              array { 
                  Employee[name!=''] ! map {
                        'Name':data(name),
                        'Date': format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f0000001]Z'),
                  'Summary': 'Employee: ' || data(name) ||'  Summary : ' || serialize(../summary)
                  }
                  }
          }"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
 {
 "Root": [
 {
  "Summary":"Employee: abc  Summary : <summary xmlns:xsi=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\"><Age>15<\/Age><tag1>dd<\/tag1><tag2>dd<\/tag2><tag2>dd<\/tag2><\/summary>",
  "Name":"abc",
  "Date":"2021-02-08T09:03:22.4740000Z"
 },
 {
  "Summary":"Employee: def  Summary : <summary xmlns:xsi=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\"><Age>15<\/Age><tag1>dd<\/tag1><tag2>dd<\/tag2><tag2>dd<\/tag2><\/summary>",
  "Name":"def",
  "Date":"2021-02-08T09:03:22.4740000Z"
  }
 ]
}
```

Fiddle:https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkM/5

I am facing issues where the summary node shows the namespaces in output. Looks like namespaces comes from XML tree which is mentioned in Employee node.How i can remove namespace.
Also in date formatting can we get fraction seconds upto 7 digits. Right now i am able to get only milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment to your previous question, you can push the element through a mode that explicitly doesn't copy namespaces:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:for-each select="Employees">
      
        <xsl:sequence select="map { 'Root' : 
                  array { 
                      Employee[name!=''] ! map {
                            'Name':data(name),
                            'Date': format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f0000001]Z'),
                      'Summary': 'Employee: ' || data(name) ||'  Summary : ' || ../summary => mf:strip-namespaces() => serialize()
                      }
                      }
              }"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:mode name="strip-namespaces" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template mode="strip-namespaces" match="*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:strip-namespaces" as="node()">
        <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$node" mode="strip-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:function>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkM/6

Comment: This works fine. Is there any option to get seconds fractions up to 7 digits instead of 3(I have included the code i used in question already)

Comment: The example https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkM/6 shows `2021-02-08T15:54:08.8710000Z`. Not sure whether the specs prescribe that or it is implementation dependent.

Comment: ok, Any references for how to call C# methods in xslt 3.0 so that i can call C# methods to do this

Comment: All such stuff very much depends on the particular processor used, the way you use it, how it or its API is exposed. Certainly not something anyone can answer in a comment to answer to an unrelated problem.